# Check String of chars

Tags: c#, string, char, contains

I'm looking for an fast method-solutions of my Problem to check a String, if this contains an min one char. IF String contains like any one of character in alphabet then return true, else false.

```
public bool checkString(String s)
{
  return true || false;
}
```

For Example:

```
"1232133432454355467" return false 
"134324239846c" return true
```

Comment: why not **String.Contains** ?

Comment: Are you wanting to check that a String is alphanumeric, or that it contains more than one character? Or both? Please explain yourself better.

Comment: not alphanumeric just only char.

Comment: Each non-emtpy string contains `char`. `char` is a type in C# representing any character. I guess you actually mean letter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var r = CheckString("112");
        Console.WriteLine(r); // false
        r = CheckString("112a");
        Console.WriteLine(r); // true
    }

    public static bool CheckString(String input)
    {
        return Regex.Match(input, @"[a-zA-Z]").Success;
        // or, as @Vlad L suggested
        //return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[a-zA-Z]");
    }
}
```

If you want to verify against the "All Letters" Unicode character class, use this one instead:

```
return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"\p{L}");
```

*Reference: [Supported Unicode General Categories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#SupportedUnicodeGeneralCategories)*

Comment: Or simply `return Regex.IsMatch(input, @"[a-zA-Z]");` :)

Answer (score 2):

If I understood the question correctly... This returns true if the string contains at least one letter.

```
    public bool checkString(String s)
    {
        return s.Any(x => Char.IsLetter(x));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with ToCharArray():

```
public bool checkString(String s)
{
    bool retValue =  s.ToCharArray()
                      .Any(c => ((int)c > 64 && (int)c < 91) || 
                                ((int)c > 96 && (int)c < 123));
    return retValue
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for sake of completion.

```
// Regex to check the value consists of letters
// with atleast 1 character
private static Regex reg = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z]+");

public bool checkString(String s)
{
    return reg.Match(s).Success;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
if (Regex.IsMatch(yourString, "[a-zA-Z]"))
{
}
```

Comment: Ye, sorry - I didn't understand what he wants. I saw after he updated his post. Corrected

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(checkString("137563475634c756"));
        }
        static  public bool checkString(String s)
        {
            return Regex.IsMatch(s, "[a-zA-Z]");
        }
```

It Returns True.